# Fitted distribution is cut when creating several plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to plot 3 figures of the normal distribution of publications but I am only getting one good figure (UK). The remaining two (USA and JAPAN) have a normal curve that is incomplete.

I fitted the curves to histograms so you could say that each figure needs to hold two graphs, i.e. a histogram and a Gaussian distribution.

Please take a look at a part of my code and let me know how to fix this. 
I am very open to suggestions, thanks.

My Matplotlib figures: [fitted distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nhfv.png), [fitted distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvTwx.png), [fitted distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lbyx.png)

```
for item in totalIPs:
    USA=totalIPs[18]
    JAPAN=totalIPs[10]
    UK=totalIPs[17]
    AUSTRALIA=totalIPs[0]

#print(USA)
#print(JAPAN)
#print(UK)
#print(AUSTRALIA)
#print('done')

#print(country)
#print(ipFirmnames)
#print(totalIPs)
#print("done")       

#Calculating mean and standard deviation
#from sublists in country list of lists
#i could write a function for this but dont know how

mu_USA=statistics.mean(USA)
mu_JAPAN=statistics.mean(JAPAN)
mu_UK=statistics.mean(UK)

std_USA=statistics.stdev(USA)
std_JAPAN=statistics.stdev(JAPAN)
std_UK=statistics.stdev(UK)

plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(USA, bins=10, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')

plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(JAPAN,bins=10,normed=True,alpha=0.6, color ='g')

plt.figure(3)
plt.hist(UK, bins=10,normed=True, alpha=0.6, color = 'g')

standardize_USA=(np.array(USA)-mu_USA)/std_USA
standardize_JAPAN=(np.array(JAPAN)-mu_JAPAN)/std_JAPAN
standardize_UK=(np.array(UK)-mu_UK)/std_UK

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()

x1=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
x2=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
x3=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)

fitted_pdf_USA=ss.norm.pdf(x1,mu_USA, std_USA)
fitted_pdf_JAPAN=ss.norm.pdf(x3,mu_JAPAN, std_JAPAN)
fitted_pdf_UK=ss.norm.pdf(x3,mu_UK, std_UK)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x1, fitted_pdf_USA, 'K', linewidth=2)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x2, fitted_pdf_JAPAN,'K', linewidth=2)
fitted_pdf_JAPAN=ss.norm.pdf(x2,mu_JAPAN, std_JAPAN)


plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(x3, fitted_pdf_UK,'K', linewidth=2)

#plt.show()
print(standardize_USA)
print(standardize_JAPAN)

#print(USA)
print(UK)
print(JAPAN)
```

Comment: First and thus far only suggestion from my side: Provide a [mcve] of the issue you want help with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to Python and Stackoverflow so I am not familiar to convention. I will keep that in mind for next time. By the way any thoughts on what's causing the problem with my plots?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want us to do even though you actually need the help and we should provide it. [PyMC](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/LKJ.html) has some sample code to help you get started; using a known framework and an step-by-step notebook significantly helps us in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is that the limit for the curve is obtained from only one curve in the part

```
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
```

Make individual limits for every plot from its respective data, not the graph limit, and it will solve your issue. Do use using `max()` and `min()` from numpy.

```
x1=np.linspace(USA.min(),USA.max(),100)
```

Do it for every plot with its respective data. This way will give smooth curves, but the limit is not the graph, but the data. If it got too small, just increase the limits through a multiplication (as `1.1*max()`) or a sum (`max()+10`; `min` depends on the data).

Comment: That's really interesting. I hope you are right because I spent ages trying to found out the fault. So do you min instead of using the limits I should use values instead? I look forward to seeing your code

Comment: @mywrathacademia Yep, using the max and min values of every set should work. However, as pointed out in the comment, your example is not enough to reproduce the problem, an edition would be good to make a better question.

Comment: And I worked. Thank you Guto, the way you spotted the problem was very impressive. I am now using the data the respective data just as you suggested. Though I had to use the sort function because the curve was very noise. I got a smoother curve for one of the data sets when I used the xmin and xmax limits compared to the actual data. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Another thing. What's the idea behind subplots? From what I read they are plots of thesame figure that are copies. Would i be able to subplots for what I am doing and would it be better than 3 figures if I am trying to fit the three normal distribution plots on one page? I'm looking for optimum quality while taking up less space on a page.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Just got back. About the Subplot, this is a discussion apart,appropriate for the chat, maybe for another question, but be careful on asking. You already got downvotes here because it is not a reproducible example ([mcve]), and i agree on that. You can talk on chat with 20 points. If you edit you question and get upvotes from the people who commented (me included) or answer another question you can get there.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia If you noticed, I recommend to use the data limits, not the data. I updated the answer. Btw, if you like my answer consider making a [tour] to understanding better how the site works, and what to do [when someone reply](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).